# Ack command not found error

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, terminal, assets

Recently I wrote a [bash script](https://gist.github.com/tariq235/ecda40b89f85a9f94716#file-removeunusedimages-sh) to delete unused images from the Xcode project. That was working fine on Mountain Lion. Today I installed latest version of Mavericks (I did clean install). But now while running the terminal command i.e.`bash removeunusedimages.sh`. I'm getting following error:

```
removeUnusedImages.sh: line 5: ack: command not found
```

I have tried searching about ack on google but still not able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installed using homebrew:

```
brew install ack
```

Note: If you're getting brew command not found error. Then you can install brew using following command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Homebrew source: http://brew.sh/

Answer (score 0):

[Ack](http://beyondgrep.com) is a tool similar to grep.  You can install it from here...

```
curl http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.12-single-file > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 !#:3
```